# What is the best way NDVI can be used for assessment of remediation level of ecosystem (after nuclear accident)?

Tags: remote-sensing, ndvi, references, environmental-monitoring

I am thinking about ways to assess efficiency of various bioremediation methodologies and self-remediation of an ecosystem polluted with nuclear waste.

I would like to use NDVI as an assessment criterion, and I would like to know whats the best way of doing it.

Comment: Do you know for certain that nuclear waste has an effect on healthy, green chlorophyll, which NDVI is a measure of? I am thinking of Chernobyl where there appears to be plenty of vegetation, though lots of nuclear pollution.